# read filters from a text file with tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

i would like to know as the title describes if there is a way read filters from a file in tcpdump
currently i use

```
tcpdump -r input.pcap -w output.pcap src host 1.1.1.1
```

and what i wan to do is make the tcpdump read the filter from a txt file, so the command would be something like

```
tcpdump -r input.pcap -w output.pcap -filter myfilter.txt
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

From a five seconds web search and the [TCPDUMP man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

> OPTIONS
>
> -F file
>           Use file as input for the filter expression. An additional expression given on the command line is ignored.

Comment: i must be tottaly blind if i missed that

Answer (score 3):

It's not specifically about `tcpdump` but you can do this with any command whatsoever with standard Unix shell "backtick"

```
$ tcpdump -r input.pcap -w output.pcap `cat myfilter.txt`
```

The `-F file` method with a specific flag is better if the command has it, as `tcpdump` does, but the backtick method will work for anything.